# How to change position of UIView with changed transform position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, transform

I have a label which I rotated clock wise. And now I want to change its y position after rotation complete. Can anyone help me to get this done? 
When I change y position it doesn't change from current position of label, its change from the previous position from where rotation started.

Comment: are you used the constarints on your label

Comment: No constraints used?

Comment: Actually I am creating a lottery wheel, where I added different label for item names in the wheel. I need to give a animation of won item, like change its y coordinate a bit. But after rotation of circle label position are changed.

Answer (score 1):

In UIView Class Reference you can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) that you should not set the frame of a view with transform property different than CGAffineTransformIdentity.

If you want to change the position of the transformed view, you should use center property. If you want to adjust the size you should use bounds property.

Answer (score 0):

Write this line after set *y position*.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];      //May this help u
```

Comment: It would be better to explain why that is needed for provide a reference for the op to understand the answer.